# Windows 10 Update KB4013429 File explorer crashing

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

This morning I updated to the new windows 10 update `KB4013429`.

Now I am unable to `right-click` any `.ts` file without FileExplorer crashing.

I found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/5zw5r3/heads_up_windows_10_kb4013429_makes_applications/) about it, tried all of the suggested solutions, but nothing seems to work. When i try to uninstall the update I recieve the error:

> An error has occurred. Not all of the updates were successfully uninstalled.

Does anyone know any other methods to fix this issue?

Note you can still open the `.ts` you just can't `right-click` anything.

---

**Update:** My colleague was successfully able to uninstall the update and now this issue is gone.

---

**Update 2:** I found this [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/kb4013429-kills-explorerexe/d48e54bb-7e8b-4289-b12c-2178c6dfb608?tab=question&status=AllReplies) on the MS forum which seems to be the same issue I am facing. An MS rep posted:

> It appears that KB4013429 is responsible for the problem you encountered

How do I unintsall / remove this update from my pc....

Comment: `My colleague was successfully able to uninstall the update and now this issue is gone.`  That is good to hear!  Please do us a favor and take a few minutes to detail the fix-action within a posted answer.  After the 2-day moratorium, you can flag your own post as the officially accepted answer to benefit the rest of the community.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Run5k I followed the identical process to what he did and recieved the aforementioned error... So in addition am trying to find any other known work arounds. Do you have any suggestions as to what would prevent an update from uninstalling ?

Comment: follow [those steps to generate a crash dump](http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU) and share the dmp file on onedrive (compresses as zip to reduce file size to down/upload. I'll look at the dump and maybe I see the cause.

Comment: @magicandre1981 looks like windows released an update https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4015438 to fix the previous update - trying this now and will report back. If it does not fix the problem then I will get that dmp. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can confirm that the newest MS [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4015438/windows-10-update-kb4015438) `KB4015438` on March 20 2017 does fix the File Explorer issue for typescript files.

Comment: looks like explorer crashes while trying to generate thumbnails for MPEG2 videos. the older update from Tuesday had issues in this case.

Comment: @magicandre1981 MPEG2's are still crashing file explorer in the newest update?

Comment: this was only a guess, because the update from Tuesday had this as a known issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4013429 **"Windows DVD Player (and 3rd party apps that use Microsoft MPEG-2 libraries) crashes when run."**